# Firebase with Room persistance library

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-room

I was thinking about fetching data from Firebase and storing it on my phone using room library. But, I have a doubt in my mind. I want to use Firebase `ChildEventListener` because I want to fetch data only when a child is changed or added. But, I also know that ChildEventListener fetches all data when the app is started for the first time. So,`my question is that in what cases firebase ChildEventListener will fetch whole data and in what cases a single child?`. Actually, knowing this is important because if ChildEventListener fetches same data twice, room will give unique id duplication error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot control when ChildEventListener is firing, an easy strategy would be to overwrite in all cases. You can avoid unique id duplication error with following code:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
```

If replace is not suitable for you there are [other options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/OnConflictStrategy).

Answer (score 1):

Classes implementing [ChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) interface can be used to receive events about changes in the child locations of a given database reference. You should use this interface only if you want to respond to child-level changes because this interface has separate methods for when a child is added, removed, changed or moved (`onChildAdded()`, `onChildRemoved()`, `onChildChanged()` and `onChildMoved()` respectively).

> In what cases firebase ChildEventListener will fetch whole data and in what cases a single child?

For example, `onChildAdded()` method is called once when you start the app to get all the children from a particular location but is also called everytime a new child is added at that location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to remove duplicate of data

`@Entity(tableName = "post",indices = @Index(value = {"id"},unique = true))`

In your model class you can give your "id" as unique so that same data will not store multiple times. Remember one point don't provide your primary key as unique you have to provide a separate id for your Room Database. hope it will help you :)